In the Unity Engine, the member field referenced by the coroutine becomes NULL
This code works fine.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

class Enemy
{
    public string enemyName = "Default Enemy Name";
    TestGameObject_002 monoBehaviour = null;
    public Enemy(TestGameObject_002 monoBehaviour)
    {

    }
}

public class TestGameObject_002 : MonoBehaviour
{
    Enemy enemy = null;

    void Start()
    {   
        enemy = new Enemy(this);
        StartCoroutine(TestCoroutine());        
    }

    public IEnumerator TestCoroutine()
    {
        if(enemy != null)   Debug.Log("TestGameObject_002.TestCoroutine(), enemy is not null");
        else                Debug.Log("TestGameObject_002.TestCoroutine(), enemy is null");

        Debug.Log("TestGameObject_002.enemy.enemyName = " + enemy.enemyName);

        yield return null;
    }
}

But for some reason, below code makes enemy null.the member field referenced by the coroutine becomes NULL. It's hard to see why, since I don't think passing a MonoBehavior by reference and calling StartCoroutine would cause any problems.
As expected, the below code should work fine.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

class Enemy
{
    public string enemyName = "Default Enemy Name";
    TestGameObject_002 monoBehaviour = null;
    public Enemy(TestGameObject_002 monoBehaviour)
    {
        this.monoBehaviour = monoBehaviour;

        monoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(monoBehaviour.TestCoroutine());
    }
}

public class TestGameObject_002 : MonoBehaviour
{
    Enemy enemy = null;

    void Start()
    {   
        enemy = new Enemy(this);
    }

    public IEnumerator TestCoroutine()
    {
//yield return null;
        if(enemy != null)   Debug.Log("TestGameObject_002.TestCoroutine(), enemy is not null");
        else                Debug.Log("TestGameObject_002.TestCoroutine(), enemy is null");

        Debug.Log("TestGameObject_002.enemy.enemyName = " + enemy.enemyName);

        yield return null;
    }
}

if you return control to the unity loop with yield before referencing enemy, it works fine.

Presumably the Start method isn't being called. You should check whether that's actually the case - because then the problem isn't "a field becomes null" but "Start isn't being called when I expect it to be".

no. Start method called.

In general your passing in this and then calling the internal coroutine.. that's feels very much like an anti pattern .. actually I wouldn't even use a class field at all but rather pass in the Enemy instance as a parameter to the Coroutine so it can in itself be self sufficient

"no. Start method called" - definitely on the same instance that's causing problems, and before your debug logging? (I'd suggest assigning some random ID on construction, then log that ID in both Start and TestCoroutine.) It seems much more likely that Start hasn't been called than that the field is being cleared magically.

Ctor has not returned but you use the Enemy ref in coroutine. There was the right answer below but some mods deleted it...
